# Doctrine2 generic entity save functionality

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm

I am creating an API.
I have all my entities created.
I am beginning to create resource classes for each entity to separate business logic. Each of my resources extends an abstract class. In that abstract class I would like to have a generic save function that would take the data parsed to it and would create or update the data in the database.
The data passed is an associative array, could either be 1 or more records and each of those records could have related record data in there.. e.g. a foreign key to bind the relationship etc. 
How would I go about doing this in the most effective and efficient manner?

Here is what I am thinking so far

```php
if(isset($data[$this->name])){
            foreach($data[$this->name] as $data_to_hydrate_entity){
                if(isset($data_to_hydrate_entity[$this->primary_key_field])){ // might need to dynamically work out the primary key
                    $entity = $this->getRepository()->find($data_to_hydrate_entity[$this->primary_key_field]);
                    // from here i should be able to hydrate the entity with the new values and then save.

                    // data update data in
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  If your data is in arrays then there is not much point in trying to use doctrine repositories.  Perhaps you could explain a bit more.

Comment: @Cerad My apologies. I will try and be clearer. A user will submit a form somewhere.. that data will then get passed to the API. At this stage the data is in the form of an associative array. I then need to take that data, convert it into the appropriate entity object and save it.
I have many entities and I don't want to map each entities object properties to the the values in the array. 
Included in this I must also take into account that the associative array may contain data of related entities. E.g. Customers have a country id

Comment: Might take a look at how Symfony handles forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html.  The Symfony Serializer component is also worth a read: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html